Why does ATSAM3X8E have two separate registers for setting and clearing bits?
I am about confused about how to use registers on ATSAM3X8E. In the datasheet for PIO, for instance, there's almost always two registers for everything.
For example, there are PIO_PER and PIO_PDR registers to enable and disable PIO register. So, if I want to enable GPIO line 1, should I both set and unset these two registers, or just setting PIO_PER is enough?
Enable with
PIO_PER = (1U << 1);

or
PIO_PER = (1U << 1);
PIO_PDR = ~(1U << 1);

Also, does the order of the two matter? what's the purpose of having two separate registers anyway?

If you want to enable one pin, you write the bit 1 which pin you want to enable. The bits that are 0 do nothing.
So your example with single enable is OK.
Your second enable might be completely wrong depending on what you want to do.
The first line enables only the bit you want. The second line disables all the other pins except the pin you just enabled. It might be what you want or not, but it will disable all other pins. The order does not matter itself, except if you wanted to do things in that order.
So the larger concept why there are separate set and clear registers is atomicity.
Imagine you want to say do something on some bit on some register. If you are familiar with "the traditional" way of doing things, to e.g. turn LED on means you need to read the data register, set the bit, and write the data regiter - i.e. a read-modify-write operation.
Imagine also that you want to control a second LED from a timer interrupt and it happens after the data register is read but before it is writen to light up the first LED. The timer interrupt also needs to do a read-modify-write on the same register. The second LED is turned on in the interrupt, but the main code returns the regiter with a value where second LED is off but first LED is on. Clearly the timer interrupt should have been prevented from happening while doing the read-modify-write for the first LED so the timer interrupt can correctly read-modify-write the second LED on too. Perhaps by disabling interrupts.
So having a separate clear and set registers are an atomic and provides "hardware acceleration" where you don't need to spend time on useless read-modify-write sequences and bother with atomicity of the operations.
This lets you e.g. set or clear some bits in one operation by telling the hardware which bits you want to set or clear and which bits you want to keep unmodified.

Just to add to @Justme's answer, this especially important on registers whose contents are modified by the microcontroller.Imagine an interrupt status register (that contains multiple interrupt sources) that is updated by the microcontroller and needs to be cleared in an interrupt service routine.  Clearing the interrupt using the read/modify/write method will cause problems if the microcontroller updates a different interrupt status in the middle of the read/modify/write.

To expand upon the mention of atomic operations in the answer, the ATSAM3X8E datasheet shows that microcontroller incorporates the ARM Cortex-M3 Bit-banding:

The regions for SRAM and peripherals include bit-band regions. Bit-banding provides atomic operations to bit data, see “Bit-banding” on page 66.

From the ARM documentation:

Bit-banding maps a complete word of memory onto a single bit in the bit-band region. For example, writing to one of the alias words sets or clears the corresponding bit in the bit-band region. This enables every individual bit in the bit-banding region to be directly accessible from a word-aligned address using a single LDR instruction. It also enables individual bits to be toggled without performing a read-modify-write sequence of instructions.
The processor memory map includes two bit-band regions. These occupy the lowest 1MB of the SRAM and Peripheral memory regions respectively. These bit-band regions map each word in an alias region of memory to a bit in a bit-band region of memory.

Where bit-band increases the number of effective peripheral addresses as aliases allow modification of single bits.
